# SQL how to fill out first line of group with value and other values to null

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Actually i have a select statement which contains a group by

```
id      id_2  test
90001   7792  abc
90002   7792  abc
90003   7792  abc
94001   7024  efg
94002   7024  efg
94003   7024  efg
```

I would like this :

```
id      id_2  test
90001   7792  abc
90002   7792  null
90003   7792  null
94001   7024  efg
94002   7024  null
94003   7024  null
```

How to do that (test value fill in first row group) with sql (pgsql) ? thanks !

I tried Partition by...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0c15aff0f7481765e157ed0dbd57b3a5)

```
SELECT
    id,
    id_2,
    CASE WHEN row_number = 1 THEN test END as test         -- 2
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id_2 ORDER BY id)  -- 1
    FROM mytable
) s
```

1. Enumerate all records of an ordered group to find the first one using the [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)
2. Keep the value if the row number is `1`, NULL else

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select id, id_2,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by id_2 order by id)
             then test
        end) as test
from t
order by id_2 desc, id;
```

Note:  It is important to have the `order by` in the outer query.  Otherwise, the SQL engine is allowed to return the results in any order.

Also, I recommend that you do this in the presentation layer rather than in the query, but that is really up to you.